# form is submitted when I open the datepicker angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have 3 buttons, two to open the datepicker and one to submit, I don't understand why when I click on the datepicker the form is submitted... dont know what else can I do

**home.component.html**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >

    <span class="from">        
      <button md-raised-button (click)="pickup.open()" ></button>
      <input  [mdDatepicker]="pickup"
              name="pickup"
              ngModel>
      <md-datepicker touchUi="true"  #pickup></md-datepicker>
    </span>

    <span class="to">
        <button md-raised-button (click)="pickupTo.open()"></button>
        <input  [mdDatepicker]="pickupTo"
                placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                name="pickupTo"
                ngModel>
        <md-datepicker touchUi="true" #pickupTo></md-datepicker>
    </span>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
onFindAWhip(form: NgForm){
    const value = form.value;
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<button md-raised-button type="button" (click)="pickupTo.open()"></button>
```

Comment: Note from Angular documentation to support this answer "Be sure to add the type="button" attribute. In fact, you should always specify a button's type. Without an explicit type, the button type defaults to "submit". When you later add a form submit action, every "submit" button triggers the submit action which might do something like save the current changes. You do not want to save changes when the user clicks the Add a Secret Lair button."

Comment: it works.. don't know why I was on the datepicker doc looking for some info,thanks